# How to write a valid xsd for days of the week ?

Tags: xml

I am new to xml and trying to write an xsd for a list of days with at least one day and no duplicates.

I would like to allow a definition of days in the following form inside the xml, for example :

```
<!-- working days -->
<days>
    monday
    tuesday
    wednesday
</days>
```

The element  cannot be empty, contain duplicates or miswritten days.

I have written the following to validate the xml :

```
<xs:simpleType name="day">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="sunday"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="monday"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="tuesday"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="wednesday"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="thirsday"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="friday"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="saturday"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="dayList">
    <xs:list itemType="day"/>
    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    <xs:maxLength value="7"/>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="days" type="dayList"/>
```

The problem with the definition above is that duplicates are still possible.
Is there a way to solve this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way in XSD 1.0 of constraining the items in a list to be unique.

It can be done in XSD 1.1 by adding an `xs:assertion` facet to dayList:

```
test="count($value) eq count(distinct-values($value))"
```